# Remove the Flutter Native Splash Screen after AppOpenAd is closed

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen, google-mobile-ads

I'm trying to implement the Flutter Native Splash new feature of preserving the splash screen until the remove() function is called. I want the splash to be removed when a user dismisses or closes the AppOpenAd. And I also want the splash screen to be preserved till the ad is loaded and shown to the user and removed when dismissed.

I'm using a secondary splash screen, Animated Splash Screen to hide the black screen when the Open App Ad is dismissed.

I tried to run the

> loadOpenAppAd

on the main function, but it was a disaster. On dismiss, the black screen couldn't come off.

```
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart';

AppOpenAd? myAppOpenAd;

loadAppOpenAd() {
  AppOpenAd.load(
      adUnitId: ids.appOpenAdUnitId,
      request: const AdRequest(),
      adLoadCallback: AppOpenAdLoadCallback(onAdLoaded: (ad) {
        myAppOpenAd = ad;
        myAppOpenAd!.show();
        myAppOpenAd!.fullScreenContentCallback= FullScreenContentCallback(
          onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (AppOpenAd ad){
            ad.dispose();
            FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
          }
        );
        FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
      }, onAdFailedToLoad: (error) {
        FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
      }),
      orientation: AppOpenAd.orientationPortrait);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
  await MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadAppOpenAd();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => OverlaySupport.global(
        child: MyBackground(
          child: MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Bojack',
            theme: ThemeData(
                scaffoldBackgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(
                    onBackground: whiteShade, 
                    onSurface: whiteShade),
             ),
            home: AnimatedSplashScreen(
              duration: 2500,
              splash: '..icon.png',
              splashIconSize: 120,
              nextScreen: isSeenOnboard == true
                  ? const DynamicPage()
                  : const OnBoardingPage(),
              splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
              pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.fade,
              backgroundColor:backgroundColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```